# Percona Server 5.5 or MariaDB on Windows

Tags: .net, mysql, windows, mariadb, percona

I am running a MySQL 5.5 on a x64 Windows Server and keep getting a auto increment id error which is a known error in MySQL.   I would like to try out Percona Server or MariaDB as they have higher benchmarks but I can't find a drop in replacement for MySql 5.5.   Can MariaDB 5.2 be used to replace MySQL 5.5 or is there a version of Percona Server that runs on Windows?  Also is anyone else using either of these on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Percona on Windows. 
Current MariaDB 5.2 is a drop-in replacement for MySQL 5.1. Upgrade wizard supplied with Maria will not offer a downgrade from 5.5. MariaDB 5.5 is in preparation, however it will need some time.

Having said this, your MySQL5.5 data might well be compatible with MariaDB 5.2, compatibility between 5.1 and 5.5 is generally good, assuming you're not using the new stuff (pluggable authentication or performance schema)

I think it is well possible to copy database directory to another place, remove performance_schema from it, copy and edit my.ini, register service with  MariaDB's mysqld.exe and run it as MariaDB.

What was the well-known problem about autoincrement?

Comment: The error I run into is http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35602.  Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine.  I keep getting the error in my dev environments as well.

Comment: I suggest to add your test case into the mentioned bug report, if you have an easy one. Perconas XtraDB (included as innodb with MariaDB) is a bunch of enhancements on top of Innodb rather than  bug fixes.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't solve the problem, now you can install MariaDB 5.5 on Windows. It is a drop-in replacement and many MySQL bugs have been solved on MariaDB. However, you should check MariaDB 5.5 changelog, or write to the MariaDB mailing list, to see if the bug that affects you has been solved. (well, if the problem is in InnoDB, it has probably been fixed by Percona in both MariaDB and Percona Server)
Percona Server works on Windows, but you have to compile and configure it by yourself. And it is REALLY fast, but it's optimized for Linux. I don't think this is the right thing to do for you.
Hoever, keep in mind that if you have a problem with AUTO_INCREMENT, there is probably and easy workaround. If you describe the bug, maybe we can help you.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see the link. But the bug you linked has been solved in 2010.